# Infinite scroll render in ReactJS with React-List using table takes too long

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, list, html-table

I want to render large lists of data inside a table. I am using the React-List library found online, but when the user scrolls about 200 items, the rest of them take too much time to load.

I achieved something like this:
[image: infinite-scroll]

After about 200 items, I get these warnings in the console, and the list starts to render slower and slower like in the image below:
[image: slow-infinite-scroll]

I use React-List for rendering this table and a get request to get all the data once, code will be shown below.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { toastr } from '../../../components/toastr/toastr.component';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faTrashAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import DaysJS from 'react-dayjs';
import Loading from '../../../components/loading/loading.component';
import Tooltip from '../../../components/tooltip/tooltip.component';
import ReactList from 'react-list';

import './error.styles.scss';

class ErrorPage extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      pending: true,
      errors: []
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/api/logError').then(resp => {
      this.setState({ pending: false, errors: resp.data });
    }).catch(() => toastr('error', 'Eroare la preluarea datelor!'));
  };

  renderItem = (index, key) => {
    return (
      <tr key={key}>
        <td>
          {this.state.errors[index].id}
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  };

  renderTable (items, ref) {
    return (
      <div style={{maxHeight: '400px', overflowY: 'scroll'}}>
        <Table bordered striped hover size="sm">
          <tbody ref={ref}>
            {items}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderRow = (index, key) => {
    const entry = this.state.errors[index]

    return (
      <tr key={key}>
        <td width='40px' className='text-center'>{index}</td>
        <td width='40px' className='text-center'>{entry.id_user}</td>
        <td width='200px'>{entry.email}</td>
        <td width='200px'>{entry.name}</td>
        <td width='200px'>{entry.action}</td>
        <td>{entry.error}</td>
        <td width='120px' className='text-center'><DaysJS format='DD.MM.YYYY - HH:MM'>{entry.createdAt}</DaysJS></td>
        <td width='30px' className='cursor-pointer text-center' data-tip data-for='tooltip'>
          <Tooltip id='tooltip' message='Șterge eroare'/>
          <FontAwesomeIcon className='text-danger' icon={faTrashAlt} />
        </td>
     </tr>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { pending, errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className='error-page mt-3 row'>
        <Loading pending={pending} />
        <div className='col-sm-4 fw-bold'>Total erori: {errors.length}</div>
        <div className='col-sm-4'>
          <h4 className='text-center'>Erori</h4>
        </div>

        <div className='col-sm-4 text-end'>
          <button className='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashAlt} className='me-1' />
            Șterge toate
          </button>
        </div>

        <div className='col-sm-12'>
          <Table bordered size="sm">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th width='40px'>Id user</th>
                <th width='200px'>Email</th>
                <th width='200px'>Unitate</th>
                <th width='200px'>Acțiune</th>
                <th>Eroare</th>
                <th width='120px'>Data</th>
                <th width='38px'></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </Table>

          <ReactList
            itemsRenderer={(items, ref) => this.renderTable(items, ref)}
            itemRenderer={this.renderRow}
            length={errors.length}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
};

export default ErrorPage;
```

I used in AngularJS a library called ng-infinite-scroll that rendered the items with no problem with infinite scroll and I tried to find something similar for ReactJS.

Comment: Check this out - https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/22928

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this library has too many issues unfortunately. Its exactly the functionality I need but with less problems.